# how many partition key for a Cassandra table?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-cli

partition key for a Cassandra table?

In customer table customerid is partition key?

Suppose I have 1 million customers in year  so I have 1 million partitions

After 10 years so I have 10 million customers or more also ... so I have 10 million paritions

SO my Question is ? 
1) if I want read customers table (10 million partition) is that affect the read performance ?

note : In single partition we may have 50 to 100 columns ?

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea in that you'll want to use data modeling to create a multi-tenant environment. The caveat is that you're not going to want to do full table/multiple partition scans in Cassandra to retrieve that data. It's pretty well documented as to why, but anytime you have a highly distributed environment, you will want to minimize the amount of network hops, data shuffling, etc. Can't fight physics :)

Anyways, it sounds like this is reporting type of use case - you're going to need to use something like Spark or some type of map and reduce to efficiently report on multiple partitions like this.